# React-Native HighCharts Boost Module Usage

Tags: react-native, boost, highcharts

I have a data set of four series each with 250000 points so approximately one million in total. I am creating an app with React Native. I tried using minimal HighCharts Wrapper but couldn't make the boost module work. Here is my App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import HighchartsReactNative from '@highcharts/highcharts-react-native'

const modules = ['boost']

export default class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        let chartSeries = []

        for(let i = 0; i < 4 ; i ++){
          let series = {data:[]};
  
          for(let i= 0; i < 2500; i++){
            let point = [i+1,Math.floor(220-Math.random(0,120)*10)]
            series.data.push(point)
          }

          chartSeries.push(series);
        } 

        this.state = {
            chartOptions: {
              boost:{
                enabled:true,
                seriesThreshold:2000
              },
              chart:{
                zoomType:'xy'
              },
              series: chartSeries
            }
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <HighchartsReactNative
                    styles={styles.container}
                    options={this.state.chartOptions}
                    modules={modules}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        flex: 1
    }
});
```

It is really simple and it renders eventually but it takes too much time. Boost module doesn't seem to work correctly. Is my usage wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

It does not work correctly, because you set the `boost.seriesThreshold` equal to `2000` what means that the chart does not switch into the boost module until it has got at least 2000 series.

I think you had intention to set the `plotOptions.series.boostThreshold` to configure the boost so that it will turn on when certain series has 2000 points, didn't you?

In sum, you just need to set the mentioned `seriesThreshold` to `1`, remove the `boost: true` (as it is redundant, and `true` by default), and then set the `plotOptions.series.boostThreshold` parameter equal to `2000`.

API References:

- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/boost.seriesThreshold
- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.boostThreshold